# Apache can't find Font Awesome files, but NginX and local file system can

Tags: apache

I am trying to use Font Awesome on my website. I am testing that site on a local Apache2 webserver. When I view that site as served by my local Apache webserver, the Font Awesome icons display as little boxes.

However, if I view that same file just by the relevant web page from my file system (I'm using Ubuntu 16.10), they display fine.

Further, I have another web server running NginX, and if I upload my HTML and CSS files there, and view the page, the Font Awesome icons display fine.

In other words, it appears that *only* Apache can not load the Font Awesome files. If I look at the network response in Firefox's developer options, I see this error:

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /icons/fontawesome-webfont.ttf was not found on this server.
```

**Why is Apache2 not finding the Font Awesome files when NginX and my local file system have no problems?**

For reference, this is the relevant CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../icons/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('../icons/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../icons/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../icons/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../icons/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Probably a configuration mismatch in your Apache configuration. Could you please add your configuration too?

Comment: @MichaelHirschler, thanks for responding. I'd be happy to supply the configuration, but which file exactly do you mean? I'm more of a web programmer than a server admin, so I'm not that adept at Apache settings.